# Redux form v8.0.1 main module field could not be resolved error in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form

I am trying to add redux-form to my project. When I use the latest redux-form version i.e. 8.0.1 it gives following error. But when I use previous version, it wont give the error mentioned below, but gives other errors in different modules.

These are my Reducer.js and Store.js.

Reducer.js

```
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form';

export default {
  form,
};
```

Reducer.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';

import reducers from './Reducer';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whitelist: ['user'],
};

const persistedReducer = persistCombineReducers(persistConfig, reducers);

const middlewares = [promiseMiddleware(), thunk];

// eslint-disable-next-line
if (__DEV__) {
  middlewares.push(createLogger());
}

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(persistedReducer, undefined, compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
  const persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor };
};
```

Now I get this error. How to fix this?

While trying to resolve module `redux-form` from file `/Users/sujin.v2px/React-Native/Changunarayan/src/redux/Reducer.js`, the package `/Users/sujin.v2px/React-Native/Changunarayan/node_modules/redux-form/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/sujin.v2px/React-Native/Changunarayan/node_modules/redux-form/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

Answer (score 0):

This is solved in v8.0.4. You should update your dependency.